# text-indent doesn't work with anchor tag

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/corinem/TtPgy/

I'm using:

```
<a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor.</a>
```

css:

```
a{text-indent:-9999px;}
```

...but this doesn't work. When I do it with another tag, for example `<p>`, it works.

I also try to add `overflow:hidden` in the css but it still doesn't work. I think that I have a concept error with this css property.

Comment: Simply add display:inline-block to your a style. text-indent does not work on pure inline element.

Comment: Why are you doing this? This is a bad practice.  Which is why I am asking why are you doing this? (: It could be  considered a black hat technique and who knows how it may or may not get penalized concerning SEO. I'd steer clear of it if you can. If it's not to make it accessible for screen readers then?

Comment: @RichardAndrewLee How can you support that suggestion? I had understood that was a good practice, so, could you prove that suggestion?

Comment: @corinem http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBLvn_WkDJ4 Matt Cuts works for google. DON'T HIDE STUFF Unless you are o.k. risking penalties than hide a way some sites are non-public sites and you don't care about seo... I get that.

Comment: @RichardAndrewLee He might be doing it to make the link look stylistically different to a normal link. Maybe it's a next/previous link that can be demonstrated by an icon. If that's the case you'd still need the text so that blind or screenreader users can read the link.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the other answers suggest you can only apply `text-indent: -9999px` to a block element. You can use `display: inline-block` or `display: block;` and it will work.

I would also suggest using

```
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Instead of `text-indent: -9999px;` since -9999px forces the browser to create a 9999px box offscreen. Learn more about this "hack" here: http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/

Answer (score 2):

tag is block but a is inline ,you must write a{text-indent:-9999px;display:inline-block;}

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that with block items.

Use:

```
p,a{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display:block
}
```

Or you can wrap your `a` tag in a block item and style that instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
p{
color: red;
font-family: tahoma;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
}

p+p{
font-family: tahoma;
text-indent: 20px;
color: red; 
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that between the paragraphs there is an empty line which is not my intention. I want to have the text without that empty line as used in books. The first paragraph is not intented.