# Safari 8 text-indent bug

Tags: css, safari

We've just launched a new site and are experiencing some problems in older versions of Safari with text-indent. A live link is supplied below, hopefully somebody can help me to debug this issue? I've never experience text-indent issue before.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#previous" id="slide-prev">Prev</a></li>
    <li><a href="#next" id="slide-next">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="#scroll-down" id="scroll-down">Scroll Down</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    padding: 2px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slide-prev, #slide-next, #scroll-down {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

#slide-prev {
    width: 18px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 -406px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

#slide-next {
    width: 18px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat -40px -406px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

#scroll-down {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat -80px -406px;
    text-indent: 9999px;
}
```

[Cross Browser Screenshots](http://www.crossbrowsertool.com/s/979007)

[Live Link](http://oakdesignstudio.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue with help from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19989199/4727821).

`text-indent` only works on block level elements, so it's a case of adding that to the CSS. I have changed my text-indent technique to include `white-space` and `overflow` as suggested by @paul-redmond, for a more full proof text-indent solution.

The key was being a block level element however.

**CSS**

```
#slide-prev, #slide-next, #scroll-down {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to hide text is using this method:

```
.hide-text{
  text-indent: 101%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-prev {
    width: 18px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 -406px;
}
```

You can add this class to each of the items to hide the text. In your code above, you are repeating a lot and I also wouldn't recommending using IDs like this in your CSS.

```
<li><a href="#previous" class="hide-text slide-prev" id="slide-prev">Prev</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi @paul_redmond. Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't seem to be helping my particular situation. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Safari is this happening in?

Comment: Can do in 4 hours as it's my own answer. Have credited your help, thanks.