# Text-indent - Not displaying text in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am new to coding and I have some issues with text-indent and safari.

On chrome and firefox, everything is ok. The problem is I made two buttons, one above the other with text next to each other and the text is not displaying on safari.

Lost 3 hours already, I don't know what to do.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLe7nnds/1/)

```css
.btn-group .button {
    background:url(https://image.ibb.co/iSdLzS/red.jpg) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: 100%; 
    display: block;
   text-indent: 105px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-kerning: normal;
    font-family: Lato,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #007896;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn-group .button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}
.btn-group .button:hover {opacity: 0.8
}

.btn-group .button2 {
    background:url(https://image.ibb.co/fskHeS/blue.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: 100%; 
    display: block;
   text-indent: 105px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-kerning: normal;
    font-family: Lato,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #007896;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn-group .button2:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}
.btn-group .button2:hover { opacity: 0.8
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="button">Reeeed</button><br>
  <button class="button2">Blue</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988970/text-indent-doesnt-work-with-anchor-tag/19989199#19989199) you will find a similar question but i tried the answer then didn't work

Then I have done that trick with `position` and tried myself , hope it will help

You have to create for the text a `p` tag and position them `absolute` but with parent button `relative` then center them vertically.

```css
.btn-group .button {
    background:url(https://image.ibb.co/iSdLzS/red.jpg) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: 100%; 
    display: block;
   text-indent: 105px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-kerning: normal;
    font-family: Lato,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #007896;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn-group .button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}
.btn-group .button:hover {opacity: 0.8
}

.btn-group .button2 {
    background:url(https://image.ibb.co/fskHeS/blue.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: 100%; 
    display: block;
   text-indent: 105px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-kerning: normal;
    font-family: Lato,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #007896;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
    position:relative;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn-group .button2:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}
.btn-group .button2:hover { opacity: 0.8
}

button p {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom:0;

}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="button"><p>Reeeed</p></button><br>
  <button class="button2"><p>Blue</p></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. So simple, yet so time consuming.